# How to handle a missing variable which the script is reading from a parameter file

Tags: shell

Need a suggestion regarding the below.

I,m writing a script which will take input from a parameter file. i.e.

### script.pamfile

```
ARCHIVE_RETENTION=2
SKIP_DATABASES=
```

The 1st parameter has value 2 and 2nd parameter value is null or empty.

### part of script.

```
grep -i ^[a-z] ${PARMFILE}| while read PARM_NAME_VALUE
do
typeset -u PARM_NAME=$(echo ${PARM_NAME_VALUE}|awk -F '=' '{print $1}')
typeset -u PARM_VALUE=$(echo ${PARM_NAME_VALUE}|awk -F '=' '{print $2}')
case ${PARM_NAME} in
ARCHIVE_RETENTION  ) ARCHIVE_RETENTION=${PARM_VALUE} ;;
SKIP_DATABASES     ) SKIP_DATABASES=${PARM_VALUE} ;;
esac
done
```

So, my question here is if the parameter value is empty I can handle it using 
`[[ -z "$var" ]]`, but please suggest if the parameter it self missing in my parameter file how can I handle it. Meaning if ARCHIVE_RETENTION parameter itself is missing in the parameter file. How this can be addressed in code ?

Appreciate your suggestions and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your script with

```
while IFS== read PARM_NAME PARM_VALUE; do ..
```

or (when your PARMFILE has no spaces around the `=`)

```
source "${PARMFILE}"
```

Both improvements don't address to your question.
When the variables are missing, you need to check them with hardcoded names.

```
# Check one field
grep -q "ARCHIVE_RETENTION=" "${PARMFILE}" || echo "Nope"
# check array with fields and more error handling
required=(ARCHIVE_RETENTION SKIP_DATABASES something_else use lowercase varnames)
for f in ${required[@]}; do
   grep -q "$f" || { echo "Parameter ${f} is missing"; exit 1; }
done
```

Comment: Thank you much. This is vary helpful.

Comment: When it helps, you can click on the left for accepting this answer.